# how to maintain session that user is already login in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wsdl

After successfully login with services call, I am showing dashboard into my application, there we have another service calls.

Problem is after running time application and then killing the app thread the link between app and services call is collapsed.

How to maintain that user is already logged if he/she login into application and kills the app. (Killing app double click home button and swipe up the app).

Do I have to call same login services on application did finished launch.
or check the user already login

My Question here is maintaining Session for accessing other services.  But from server side its always says user is not login In after killing app from back ground.

@All
Your info helpful in make for integration services.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You should keep that info in `NSUserDefaults`. And then use the app delegate methods to call necessary services to restore the app to the required state

Answer (score 3):

You can set a `BOOL` value to `NSNumber` object and add it to `NSUserDefault` when the login finish.

```
NSUserDefaults *boolUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[boolUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] 
                     forKey:@"loginStatus"];
```

Later you'll be able to retrieve that value as plain BOOL using `-boolForKey:` function in `NSUserDefaults` and based on that you can check if a user is already logged in.

Also you can maintain in Local database, coredata etc based on your requirement.

**UPDATE**

If you want to maintain the session, You can ask the server team to provide you an accesstoken on the login API response & save that as a String in `NSUserDefaults` and pass that string in your service calls.

Comment: My Question here is maintaining Session for accessing other services.  But from server side its says user is not login in.

Comment: Yes, When you first logged in , from server side they must send you an access token, That too you save & send that in other API calls.

Answer (score 1):

If login is success, have below.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];
```

For checking use below.

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] valueForKey:@"isLoggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"yes") {
    NSLog(@"You are logged in");
} else {
    NSLog(@"You are not logged in");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your server implementation. Usually, when logged in, the client(mobile app) will receive a token. This token should be included in the requests made afterward to show to the server that this user is logged in.

The http header is a good place to start to check whether some token is set when the login api is returned from the server. If yes, you may need to save that token:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setValue:token forKey:@"loginToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then, if the app is killed, upon launch:

```
NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] valueForKey:@"loginToken"];
//set the token to http header
```

Comment: may i ask which library are you using for the http calls? AFNetworking? @kiran